# How can I keep a value in a text input after a submit occurs?

Tags: php, validation, forms

I want to validate a form to make sure a user writes in a name and last name.

If a user writes in only his last name, the form should show again with an error message beside the last name field, but the name value should **still** be there.

I don't know how to do this, hehe. I'm just a newbie PHP programmer.

Here's what I have so far:

```
<html>
<head>
</head>

<body>
    <form action="formprueba.php" method="get">
        <dl>
            <dt>Last Name:</dt>
            <dd><input type="text" value="" name="name" />
                <?php if((isset($_GET['name'])) && ($_GET['name'] == "")){
                    echo "Please write a correct name.";
                }
                ?>
            </dd>                

            <dt>Last Name:</dt>
            <dd><input type="text" value="" name="lastname" />
                <?php if((isset($_GET['lastname'])) && ($_GET['lastname'] == "")){
                    echo "Please write a correct last name.";
                }
                ?>
            </dd>

            <br />                
            <dt>
                <input type="submit" value="enviar" />
            </dt>
            <input type="hidden" name="enviado" value="j"/>
        </dl>
    </form>
</body>
```

Also, I'm sure this validation is horrible, if you have a couple of minutes, I'd be really grad if someone can show me a more efficient way to validate (without using third party addons).

Thanks SO.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Place the variable you need into the "value" field of your input-tag like this:

```
<input type="text" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_GET['lastname']); ?>" name="lastname" />
```

AND it's important to quote at a minimum the HTML characters someone might put in (by htmlspecialchars).

Comment: To handle undefined index notice when $_GET isn't set, I usually do this somewhere at the top of scripts

    $lastname = isset($_GET['lastname'])?$_GET['lastname']:'';

Answer (score 3):

> If a user writes in only his last
>   name, the form should show again with
>   an error message beside the last name
>   field, but the name value should still
>   be there.

Just get their value from `$_GET` (the form method you are using)

```
<input type="text" value="" name="lastname" value="<?php echo $_GET['lastname'];?>" />
```

and so on....

You **must** also use `htmlspecialchars` function for security reasons.

**[More Information Here.](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php)**

Comment: **must** not could. Failing to sanitize the data before it goes out of the system will open the site up to XSS attacks.

Answer (score 1):

If you are doing something like

```
<input type="text" value="" name="lastname" value="<?php echo $_GET['lastname'];?>" />
```

never never ever forget to check/escape the value you display using e.g. htmlentities().
Otherwise you are open to completely trivial javascript injection attacks!

Answer (score 0):

You could use client side javascript - you save a trip to the server this way.

The downside though : you can really only do basic checking as the user cannot be trusted (for security measures of course ).  You can at least "flag" the invalid patterns before making an expensive trip to the server.

Comment: I need a PHP only solution right now. :P I'll look into that when I hand in this little homework. Could just describe what I need to do? I don't necessarily want all the code just handed to me.

Comment: Client side JS would save a trip to the server, but it requires trusting the user. It can only be a "nice for the user" and never a substitute for real checking.

Answer (score 0):

just a small note i had to learn the hard way: displaying an error message and urging the user pressing the back-button (or doing the same using javascript) does *not* in general preserve values in the input fields.

This seems to be completely browser-specific, e.g. for me it worked on Safari, but not on Firefox...

Answer (score 0):

Its good to do validations on the server side. Your approach seems to be right. You can just maintain a flag which will tell you at the end of the page weather or not the validation was successful.

Example

$flag=ture;

```
<?php if((isset($_GET['lastname'])) && ($_GET['lastname'] == "")){
       echo "Please write a correct last name.";
       $flag="false";
}
?>
```

then at the bottom of the page
 if($flag==true)
       echo "form submit";

About persistence of value one of the person has correctly mention adding value to your input tag

```
value="<?php echo $_GET['lastname'];?>"
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score -1):

Add this to your form where you first declare it:

```
<form onsubmit="event.preventDefault(); validateMyForm();">
```

Comment: Why should the OP "at this to forme"? A **good answer** will always have an explanation of what was done and why it was done in such a manner, not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO.

Answer (score -2):

I think, Javascript is the best answer if you can rely on Javascript. But client side script can be over-ridden. So validate your input on the server later.