# Does "header()" php function unset global variables?

Tags: php, html, forms, post, get

I am developing a php script which contains an html form.

If not all fields are filled in the correct way the script will signal an error and redirect back to the same page with the header function setting an error variable to yes with the get method:

```
header("Location: registration_page.php?error_empty=yes");
```

my script has an error handling part in which it highlights the fields containing a mistake, but I would like to keep the value of the fields correctly filled.

I am implementing this feature as I found in this other question:

[How can I keep a value in a text input after a submit occurs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2296347/how-can-i-keep-a-value-in-a-text-input-after-a-submit-occurs)

but the problem is that when the page reopens the forms will not contain the old values.

My question is: does anybody know if the header function unsets global variables in the $_REQUEST array?

And do you know what kind of solution could I adopt?Maybe sessions?

Thanks in advance,

Matteo!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`$_COOKIES` will stay set, but `$_POST` & `$_GET` will be destroyed, as the client is moving to a new page.  If they need to be retained, they must first be stored into `$_SESSION` before calling the redirect.

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['last_post'] = $_POST;
header("Location: http://example.com");
exit();

// On the redirected page, use the stored POST values and unset them in $_SESSION
session_start();
if (empty($_POST) && isset($_SESSION['last_post'])) {
  $post = $_SESSION['last_post'];
  unset($_SESSION['last_post']);
}
else $post = $_POST;
```

Comment: after starting the session when should I destroy it? when the fields have all been filled successfully?

Comment: @Matteo `session_destroy()` is called implicitly when the script execution completes.  You don't need to call it unless you have a reason to close the session before the script is done.  `session_destroy()` _does not_ remove the session variables. I just disconnects the current script from the session.

Comment: @Matteo see addition above about unsetting the `$_SESSION` stored post after using it

Answer (score 3):

> Does anybody know if the header function unsets global variables in the $_REQUEST array?

No, it doesn't. Cookies (`$_COOKIE`) will remain.

Obviously `$_GET` will contain whatever you have in the redirect (eg: `$_GET['error_empty'] = 'yes') and`$_POST` will be empty because you aren't posting.

So it `$_REQUEST` will be a combination of `$_COOKIE` and the new `$_GET` parameters you set.

---

You probably shouldn't be using `$_REQUEST` anyway. Specify exactly where you expect your request parameters to be...

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't, but it does make a new request. A new request means a new `$_REQUEST` which does not necessarily have all of the old data. `$_COOKIE` will still be there but `$_GET` and `$_POST` will be new meaning that `$_REQUEST` will reflect that. (`$_FILES` will also be empty and while it is not in `$_REQUEST, it is another user-supplied value will be reset).

If you want to restore the form, you'll need to either put all of the variables in the url in the header, or use `$_SESSION` or `setcookie` and then restore from `$_GET`, `$_SESSION` or `$_COOKIES`.

Comment: so old values will not be accessible anymore?that's why if a use the command
     <?php echo $_REQUEST['username'];?>

the result will be empty?

Comment: `$_FILES` was removed from `$_REQUEST` a long time ago.

Comment: That's right. Because the `$_REQUEST` depends on input from the browser, if the browser makes a new request, then `$_REQUEST` is emptied.

Comment: @Null Bad wording on my part. fixed.