# Persina datepicker doesn't keep the previous chosen date after clicking submit button

Tags: asp.net-core

I'm implementing asp.net core 3.1. I'm using a persian datepicker and for implementing it I'm using below links:
https://github.com/Mds92/MD.BootstrapPersianDateTimePicker

https://forums.asp.net/post/6272109.aspx

My code to implement it is like the following:

```
public class MainViewModel
    {
        public string StartDate { get; set; }
        public string EndDate { get; set; }
}
```

Here is my code in Index view:

```
        <form method="post" style="height: 4rem;">

        <div class="col-sm-9 col-12 text-left row  align-items-center">

            <div class="border-light col-3 input-group" style="margin-right: 3.5rem !important;">
                <div class="input-group-append text-self-center form-control center p-2 pl-2 bg-light col-4">
                    <span class="oi oi-calendar pl-2"></span><span>from </span>
                </div>
                <input type="text" id="StartDate" name="StartDate" class="form-control datepicker" placeholder="@ViewBag.StartDate" />
            </div>

            <div class="border-light col-3 input-group">
                <div class="input-group-append text-self-center form-control center p-2 pl-2 bg-light col-4 ">
                    <span class="oi oi-calendar pl-2"></span><span>till </span>
                </div>
                <input type="text" id="EndDate" name="EndDate" class="form-control datepicker" placeholder="@ViewBag.EndDate" />
            </div>
          
        <div class="border-light col-2 input-group">
        <input type="submit" value="submit" asp-action="Index" class="btn btn-outline-dark p-0 px-2" />

            </div>
        </div>
 </form>
<script>
      $(function () {
                $(".datepicker").each(function () {
                    var kk = '#' + $(this)[0].id;
                    $(this).MdPersianDateTimePicker({
                        targetTextSelector: kk,
                        dateFormat: 'yyyy-MM-dd',
                        isGregorian: false,
                        enableTimePicker: false,
                        
                    });
                });
            });
</script>
```

And here is my Index and BuildIndexModel method in Controller:

```
   public IActionResult Index(MainViewModel m)
    {
       

        string startDate = String.IsNullOrEmpty(m.StartDate) ? PersianDateTime.Now.Date.ToString(format: "yyyy/MM/dd").PersianToEnglish() : FaToEn(m.StartDate);

        string endDate = String.IsNullOrEmpty(m.EndDate) ? PersianDateTime.Now.Date.ToString(format: "yyyy/MM/dd").PersianToEnglish() : FaToEn(m.EndDate);
        string regionID = Request.Form["RegionList"].ToString();

        return (BuildIndexModel(startDate, endDate, regionID));
    }

   public IActionResult BuildIndexModel(string StartDate, string EndDate,string RegionID)
        {
            ViewBag.StartDate = String.IsNullOrEmpty(StartDate) ? PersianDateTime.Now.Date.ToString(format: "yyyy/MM/dd").PersianToEnglish() : StartDate;
            ViewBag.EndDate = String.IsNullOrEmpty(EndDate) ? PersianDateTime.Now.Date.ToString(format: "yyyy/MM/dd").PersianToEnglish() : EndDate;
            ViewBag.Region = String.IsNullOrEmpty(RegionID) ? "01" : RegionID;


            StartDate = String.IsNullOrEmpty(StartDate) ? PersianDateTime.Now.Date.ToString(format: "yyyyMMdd").PersianToEnglish() : StartDate.Replace("/", "");
            EndDate = String.IsNullOrEmpty(EndDate) ? PersianDateTime.Now.Date.ToString(format: "yyyyMMdd").PersianToEnglish() : EndDate.Replace("/", "");
            RegionID = String.IsNullOrEmpty(RegionID) ? "01" : RegionID;

            MainDashboardViewModel MDVM = new MainDashboardViewModel();

            MDVM.StartDate = StartDate;
            MDVM.EndDate = EndDate;

            return View(MDVM);
}
```

When I choose my considering date from the datepickers, my project runs perfect, however, if I choose a date from one of datepickers while not selecting any date from the other one, the other one doesn't keep the previous chosen date and its date changes to todays date. I appreciate if any one tells me how can I keep always the previous dates on the date picker if I don't change the datepickers dates after clicking on submit button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are setting the start and end dates you are doing

```
string startDate = String.IsNullOrEmpty(m.StartDate) ? PersianDateTime.Now.Date.ToString(format: "yyyy/MM/dd").PersianToEnglish() : FaToEn(m.StartDate);

string endDate = String.IsNullOrEmpty(m.EndDate) ? PersianDateTime.Now.Date.ToString(format: "yyyy/MM/dd").PersianToEnglish() : FaToEn(m.EndDate);
```

so if either is not set you will set it to today's date.

Now, when the user submits the form having set both the start and end dates in your input elements it all works fine. But when you do it the next time if the user has not explicitly set one of the values again it will be submitted as null and so they will see today's date.

You'll need to set the value in the input elements. For example by:

```
value="@Request.QueryString['startDate']"
```

and similarly for endDate

This answer [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2296347/how-can-i-keep-a-v alue-in-a-text-input-after-a-submit-occurs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2296347/how-can-i-keep-a-value-in-a-text-input-after-a-submit-occurs) has some useful information including remembering to sanitize the string the user has input (in case it contains malicious code).

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer. If I understand your idea correctly, I should add a "value" property inside my input tag like the following:

Comment: Hi, your comment doesn't have anything following so I can't see the input tag.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer. If I understand your idea correctly, I should add a "value" property inside my input tag like the following:   <input type="text" id="StartDate" name="StartDate" class="form-control datepicker" value="@Model.StartDate"     placeholder="@ViewBag.StartDate" /> But now the problem is datepicker becomes disable and its default value on the textbox is like 13990709 which the correct format should be like 1399/07/09

Comment: I also used [DataType(DataType.Date)]
        [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy/MM/dd}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = false)] on top of public string StartDate { get; set; } and public string EndDate { get; set; } in my MainViewModel, but the format doesn't change and the datepicker is disable

Comment: I'm not really familiar with asp.net, but this [link]https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-pages/overview/getting-started/introducing-aspnet-web-pages-2/form-basics#remembering-what-the-user-entered looks very helpful. Basically, because on submit your whole page gets rewritten you need to make sure that the input element has value="whatever the submitted value was". I will look further to understand exactly what syntax you need, but  you know more about asp.net than me so you can probably find it! Let me know if you do.

Comment: It looks as though you need to use value="@Request.QueryString['startDate']" and similarly for endDate. Sorry I don't have a system I can test this on. Let me know what happens.